# Gedit plugin to imitate TextMate space and tab functionality

Tags: linux, gedit

I saw that nice TextMate functionality that shows a little arrow on tabulation and that `¬` symbol that is usefull to trace unnecessary whitespaces.

I have gmate plugins, but this functionality doesnt seems to be there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gedit ships with a plugin called "Draw Spaces" which will show characters for all whitespaces including tabs, spaces and line feeds. Simply enable it in `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Plugins` > `Draw Spaces`.

Comment: and if you don't have it on your list do
`sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins`